# Нужно ли ставить двоеточие перед цитированием вопроса в этом конкретном случае?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие

***"Я видел это на сайте", - теперь это такой  частый ответ на вопрос: "Откуда ты это знаешь?".***

Правильно ли здесь расставлены знаки препинания?

Answer (score 1):

"Я видел это на сайте" — теперь это такой частый ответ на вопрос: "Откуда ты это знаешь?"

Перед тире не нужно ставить запятую, согласно правилу:

_1. После закрывающих кавычек ставится только тире (независимо от того, каким знаком препинания заканчивается прямая речь) в тех случаях, когда в последующих авторских словах содержится характеристика прямой речи, ее оценка и т. д. (авторская ремарка начинается словами так говорит, так указывает, вот что сказал, вот как описывает и т. п.):

«Ничего не случилось» — так говорил ум;

«Случилось» — так говорило сердце;

«Нет ничего прекраснее этих снежных вершин» — так описывает эту местность один путешественник;

«Будь внимателен и осторожен!» — вот что он сказал мне на прощание._

В конце предложения не нужна точка, так как прямая речь заканчивается вопросительным знаком.